# TF14047: The comment exceeds the maximum allowed length of 2048 characters

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We are using the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility but we keep getting the 'TF14047: The comment exceeds the maximum allowed length of 2048 characters.' error by one changeset.

I've used a query to our TFS database to cut all the comments off after a length of 2000 characters but i keep getting the error.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

OpsHub, and all migration tools, append a stamp to the comment that has the meta data of where and when the changeset came from.

An existing changeset plus that meta exceeds the maximum comment length.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't think that's the issue. In the OpsHub log i see the comment that have more characters. When i search for the comment in our DB i can't find the comment in the [tbl_ChangeSet]. Is there another spot where comments are logged in the DB?

Comment: No idea I don't mess with the operational store in TFS.

Answer (score -1):

Because of the way OpsHub Migration Utility has been modeled. For an existing failure, change in your source system does not affect the migration.

In the pop-up that shows the error in the OpsHub UI, you will see a field called changeset id. Please refer your on-premises TFS for this changeset and see how big the comment is.
(Although, if you changed the comments through Database operation, as you said you did, this will no longer be the case)

We can help you progress the migration through a patch. Please contact us at ovsmu@opshub.com and refer this thread in the mail. And we'll help you with this issue.

Comment: Thnx! I just sent the details to ovsmu@opshub.com